# regular expression pattern in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Please help finding the correct pattern of the following case

simple strings are:

```
pdf/20120102/A1_standard.pdf
pdf/20130431/1.pdf
pdf/20110506/abcde.pdf
pdf/20131201/fff-01/02/12/-A1.pdf
```

The substring i need to match is A1_standard.pdf , 1.pdf, abcde.pdf , fff-01/02/12/-A1.pdf
I have tried `///*.pdf/` as the pattern but it seems not working. The case 4 is more difficult as there is a  '/' in the filename, if it can not be sloved right now, just ingore this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$str  = 'pdf/20120102/A1_standard.pdf';
preg_match('/(?P<file>[\w\-]+\.pdf)$/',$str,$match);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($match);

echo $match['file'];
```

Comment: `\w` matches the `-` character?

Comment: @DreamEater : Yeah it is not, let find solution for that, and i will update